# R.xml.xyz not generated for xml file for PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, xml, resources, preferences, sharedpreferences

after creating a res/xml/preferences.xml file for my PreferenceActivity I wanted to load it in the onCreate(..) method. The preferences.xml file has no problems and is simple and straightforward:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/cfg_preferences">
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="com.blabla.SetSilent"
            android:title="@string/cfg_set_silent" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The string exists in the res/values/strings.xml file and there are no red markings in the Eclipse xml file editor.

But the R.xml.preferences constant ist not generated! There are no other problems like this, but only this one is not generated. The Eclipse Projects API Level is set to 7 / 1.6.

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Update: Actually it is generated, but not visible for the Eclipse Editor for some reason. Looks like a Bug in the Ecipse Android Tools...

Comment: I found the Problem. A real stupid one. There exists a android.R class as well, which I accidently imported instead of mine.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Can't see anything wrong with your xml. Sometimes, eclipse doesn't pick up new files properly. Have you tried:

a) Clean project
OR
b) Delete R.java

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I found the problem. See my comment on the question. It was an wrong import....

Comment: A yes, that's happened to me a few times too :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The preferences.xml was supposed to be located at res/xml, but instead it was at /res/layout. So

1. Cut->Paste preferences.xml file to the res/xml folder
2. Clean your project.

That solved my problem.

Comment: Hi, I solved to problem allready two years ago ;) But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

remove the R import from your imports and try again.

I had following error

```
import android.R;
```

I removed this and imported the correct R it worked.